# Change the style of text in a string

Tags: jquery, css, replace

I've following HTML tag:

```
<td>Akshay Hulyalkar</td>
```

I want to change the style of `'Aks'` in the above HTML tag like as follows.

```
<td><span style="font-weight:bold;color:#808080">Aks</span>hay Hulyalkar</td>
```

I've tried as follows.

```
      text = $('td').html();
      text = text.replace(chars, '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:#808080">'+chars+'</span>');
      $(this).html(text);
```

But it's not replacing the original one. Is it correct what I'm doing?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$('td').html(function (_, html) {
    return html.replace(/(Aks)/, '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:#808080">$1</span>');
});
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2QFLk/)

Answer (score 4):

Well a TD shouldn't be outside of a table, but I'm assuming you only posted relevant code. Here's how I got it to work:

Demo:   http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/e5Rtr/

```
var text = $("td").text();
var chars = "Aks";
console.log(text);

text = text.replace(chars, '<span style="font-weight:bold; color:#808080;">'+chars+'</span>');

$("td").html(text);
```

Comment: +1 from me, you beat me to it, while i was creating my version on jsfiddler http://jsfiddle.net/Raver0124/fr3BF/

Comment: @tymeJV u got it,I have already ans like same,but I got it down

Comment: It works only if there's only one table that has only one td element, which I kinda doubt would happen in real life. See http://jsfiddle.net/e5Rtr/3/

Comment: I doubt it too..but without more info from the OP, it's hard to customize this more..

Answer (score 1):

What does `$(this)` refer to in this case? Wouldn't you want to do this instead?

```
text = $('td').html();
text = text.replace(chars, '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:#808080">'+chars+'</span>');
$('td').html(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do this:

```
var spanText = $('td');
var chars = "Aks";
spanText.html(spanText.text().replace(chars, '<span>'+chars+'</span>'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kfzHF/1/)

I think this is what you're looking for but, you don't ever declare `chars` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$("td").css('color','#808080');
$("td").css('font-weight','bold');
```

and as per your code try

```
text = $('td').text(); //retrive the text
text = text.replace(chars, '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:#808080">'+chars+'</span>');
$('td').html(text);   //put it as like html
```

Comment: @Gautam3164 I've asked to replace that string. I know what you've written

Comment: There is no `span` tag.  You read the question backwards.  I did the same thing initially.

Comment: No he is using .html for the retriving...see it

Comment: I see. Why would it make any difference?

Comment: he wants to replace as text but not as per the html content,there is much diff between them

Comment: @Gautam3164 The first bit of html is what he is starting with.  There is nothing but text inside so `.html` and `.text` are the same.  What is `$(this)`?  That is where the problem lies.

Comment: Here it may but in general we need to use like that only

Comment: You can see the @tymeJV answer also

Comment: If you use `.text()` to retrieve the contents, you lose all markup inside the tag. And if `.text()` works, there's no reason why `.html()` wouldn't, so this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you seen the question..........."change the style of text in a string".???plz see it

Comment: @Gautam3164 Have *you* seen the question? The problem is that *the original `<td>` doesn't change*. You won't solve it by changing `.html()` to `.text()`.

Comment: And the OP doesn't want to style the td tags. He wants to style the span.

Comment: Yes, it works for Tyme's answer. [It won't work for your answer](http://jsfiddle.net/e5Rtr/2/).

Comment: See you have placed  text = $('td').text(); //retrive the text twice